# Goal line in donut chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm trying to modify Highchart's donut/pie chart to look something like this:
[image: modified donut chart]

I've modified a jsfiddle of their pie chart to look somewhat like it. But I'm running into problems creating that little "GOAL > 55%" tick mark and text. For other charts, like a stacked bar chart, I've been able to use a plotLine on the yAxis, but that isn't working here (which probably makes sense, because a pie chart doesn't really have a yAxis):

```
yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: "Hi there"
        },
        plotLines:[
          {
           color: 'red',
           dashStyle: 'dash',
           value: 6,
           width: 4,
          }
         ]
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alexschoolzilla/cehL81ue/1/

Any ideas of how to do this for a pie chart?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I wouldn't use this type of display (a bar chart or bullet graph is so much better suited!), but, if I were going to, I wouldn't start with a donut, I would start with a Solid Gauge type, as in the Activity Gauge demo: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity, and use a regular plot line (ie http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/rqLhajw2/ )

Comment: Thanks, those are great suggestions! The fiddle does exactly what I needed. If you want to make this the answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I think this type of display is terribly inefficient and ineffective.

Plot lines do not appear to be supported with Pie Charts, for reasons that are relatively clear given the actual purpose and layout of a pie chart. However, it is achievable with Highcharts, and I would use the solid gauge as a base, using their "Apple Activity Gauge" demo as a starting point:

- http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity

You can add a `plotLine` to the `yAxis` to achieve the target line, and you can adjust all of the other display settings to your needs. A quick, rough example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/jjgw4mn4/

[image: screenshot 1]

That said, I feel obligated to include that I would much prefer to display this type of information as a bullet graph, or, a simplified version of just a bar graph with a target line.

An example using bar charts:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/m2fLd6ey/

[image: screenshot 2]

FWIW

Comment: While this answer might solve the OP's problem, the OP's question is unanswered.

Comment: @Clint in what sense is the question not answered? Are you looking for something in particular...?

Comment: The question is how to make a goal line or a plot line in a pie chart. I suspect it's not possible but if that is the case it should say so

Comment: @Clint what "should say so"? I'm not sure where Highcharts would list all of the things that are not possible on a pie chart. The answer is: don't use a pie chart for this since a goal line on a pie chart doesn't make sense and doesn't appear to be supported, and there *are* other chart types that are appropriate to accomplish what the OP was trying to accomplish.

Comment: The answer. All I'm saying is that people (like myself) will end up here looking to make plot lines on pie charts, not gauges. And although gauges are definitely a great alternative, the answer should mention that pie charts do not support plot lines.